# object cache for java unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I am not sure what the correct technical term for the test scenario I am thinking about; but here are the features that I want to be able to do during mu unit testing:

1. Instead of going to database I want a frame work that will store (serialized to disk) objects that I can pass to my unit test methods.
2. I should be able to create these objects from a DB source and save them to use later in my UNIT test cases.
3. The object store should be portable (like hsqldb file based DB that I can move around from system to system).

Is there a technical term for framework/library for such requirement? Object Database/Object store etc? Please note that I am not trying to install/configure an entire database rather I want to be able to re-create an already created complex Object structure and pass it onto a junit test method.

Comment: Why not just use hsqldb, and save the file? Other than that, look at storing the objects as JSON or XML.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell yes, that's a possibility. But the problem with that is everytime I need an object; I also need to execute the desirialization and serialization code. Furthermore it will be stored as a blob object and hence I now need 2 layers (1 DB and java layer to read/write blob back to DB).

Comment: sorry, I imagined that you already had the read/write layer,  because you probably already use the DB.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell that's ok. Actually I am pretty sure the software community has faced these issues and hence might have an intelligent solution. I am tired of hand coding the data objects in my junit test cases.